# Error malformed array literal: must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
UPDATE public.user_item
    set instructions = concat('[', array_to_string(instructions::Text[], '", "')', ']')
    where instructions is not null;
```

It fails with error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "["ERYTHRITOL, STEVIA LEAF EXTRACT, NATURAL FLAVORS."]"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

type of field 'instructions' is text

Comment: What are you trying to do there? You are converting a string to an array to convert it back to an array, then implicitly convert it to string - that doesn't make sense to me.  Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample input data and the expect result.

Comment: Array (string) _literals_ need to be [enclosed](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) with `'{...}'` the square brackets are only used when using the array keyword, e.g. `array[1,2,3]`

Comment: tried to change [] with {}, but no luck

Comment: You should add the table definition and tell what you are trying to achieve.